# Geb getItem from LocalStorage

Tags: local-storage, geb, web-storage

I testing my web app with [geb](http://www.gebish.org/).

How i can get item from site localStorage using GEB?

Any help?

I look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630207/how-to-use-selenium-to-store-values-between-tests), but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem.
I add [LocalStorage.java](https://gist.github.com/roydekleijn/5073579) class from my project and use:

```
    LocalStorage localStorage = new LocalStorage(driver);
    def output = localStorage.getItemFromLocalStorage("example");
    return output;
```

Thanks @roydekleijn!